# Change the T4 POCO Entity Framework Template to inherit from my base class

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, c#-4.0, t4

I'm trying to create a solution with layered architecture and self tracking entities.
I used the Entity Framework C# POCO Entity Generator i download from Extensions Online Gallery.
I separated the context.tt with the entities.tt on they're own class libraries.
Mapped the entities.tt to the Model. Now i need to make these classes inherit from a base class i created in another class library. Unfortunately i know nothing about changing the T4 template. Can someone help me on this problem to continue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tt file search for

```
foreach (EntityType entity in ItemCollection.GetItems<EntityType>().OrderBy(e => e.Name))
```

And then look for a line that has

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
```

Then add your interface to the end of it.

Comment: Thank you, can you provide some help on adding namespaces on each entity and DataContract DataMember attributes?

Comment: I would need to know what you are trying to accomplish?Create a new question? or update the above.